# How to display the number of objects in a tooltip angular

Tags: angular, tooltip

Im using the antdesign table to display the records , where iam having the column called color.In the table data of the color column ,showmore will be there , if iam hover the showmore it have to display the values of the color in the tooltip. Color values are in the form of array objects .how can we show those multiple objects in a tooltip.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o9sfai-d7h5dv?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts
Attached the stackblitz for better understanding.
If you hover it you can see the values shows in tooltip ,but it is showing the last object only, how can we display all objects in a tooltip, Any answers would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

if you has severals variables you need severals variables :)

In your case, if you iterate over details, you can add a new property to each element of `details`

```
this.details.forEach(element => {
      //see how you add a new property only using "element.detailText"
      element.detailsText = `Order: ${element.order}\nFamily Color: ${
        element.familyColor
      }\npantoon: ${element.pantoon}\n\n`;
    });
```

After, when you loop over details, you use the variable of the For

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let det of details">
<!--see that you use "det.detailText"-->
<!--"det" is the variable in the *ngFor, let det-->
<span
    [matTooltip]="det.detailsText" 
    matTooltipClass="tooltip-list">
  TODO List (hover)
</span>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: whatever the suggestion you made , it will add the number of ToDoList since you are using ngFor Loop and adding the tooltip inside the container, where that is not my recruitment, my recruitment is need to show all the objects of an array in a single tooltip

Answer (score 1):

Convert your array to string and assign it to `matTooltip`

```
detailsText: string = "";

  constructor() {
    debugger;
    this.details.forEach(d => {         
      this.detailsText +=
        d.order + ". " + d.familyColor + " - " + d.pantoon + "\n";
    });
  }
```

and add css in your component css file

```
.mat-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Html:

```
<span
    [matTooltip]="detailsText"
    matTooltipClass="tooltip-list">
  TODO List (hover)
</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning data to detailsText which is list in the wrong way. Hence only last object is appearing in tooltip. push the data in detailsText as follows.

```
this.detailsText.push( `Order: ${element.order}\nFamily Color: ${
        element.familyColor
      }\npantoon: ${element.pantoon}\n\n`);
    })
```

[image]